# Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1[XXX]' to type 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[xxx]'

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am using generic filter/sorting using repository pattern in asp.net core.Keep getting the error

> Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet'1[Data.Models.AdminRole]' to type 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable'1[Data.Models.AdminRole]'.

```
public virtual async Task<ICollection<T>> SearchAsync(SearchQuery<T> searchQuery)
{
    IQueryable<T> sequence = _entities.Set<T>();
    sequence = ManageFilters(searchQuery);
    sequence = ManageIncludeProperties(searchQuery, sequence);
    sequence = ManageSortCriterias(searchQuery, sequence);
    return await GetTheResult(searchQuery, sequence);
}
```

The error appears in the else part of the below code `entity =((IOrderedQueryable<T>)entity).OrderBy(x => (true));`. Since the sequence from the `ManageFilters` is not converted to the query as shown in the screen shot.

```
protected virtual IQueryable<T> ManageSortCriterias(SearchQuery<T> searchQuery, IQueryable<T> entity)
{
    if (searchQuery.SortCriterias != null && searchQuery.SortCriterias.Count > 0)
    {
        var sortCriteria = searchQuery.SortCriterias[0];
        var orderedSequence = sortCriteria.ApplyOrdering(entity, false);

        if (searchQuery.SortCriterias.Count > 1)
        {
            for (var i = 1; i < searchQuery.SortCriterias.Count; i++)
            {
                var sc = searchQuery.SortCriterias[i];
                orderedSequence = sc.ApplyOrdering(orderedSequence, true);
            }
        }
        entity = orderedSequence;
    }
    else
    {
        entity = ((IOrderedQueryable<T>)entity).OrderBy(x => (true));
    }
    return entity;
}
```

To manage the filter. Since when I don't have any filter the condition goes to the else part and then produces an error in the `ManageSortCriterias` method else part.

```
protected virtual IQueryable<T> ManageFilters(SearchQuery<T> searchQuery)
{
    IQueryable<T> sequence = _entities.Set<T>();
    if (searchQuery.Filters != null && searchQuery.Filters.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var filterClause in searchQuery.Filters)
        {
            sequence = _entities.Set<T>().Where(filterClause);
        }
    }
    return sequence;
}
```

The below screen shot show the sequence data as it is internal.

[image: added query]

Comment: You don't need the (apparently wrong) cast, so simply remove it - e.g. `entity = entity.OrderBy(x => (true));`. Also unrelated, but the `ManageFilters` implementation contains a bug - `sequence = _entities.Set<T>().Where(filterClause);` should be `sequence = sequence.Where(filterClause);`